# Creating an IronPython (dynamic) object from a string

Tags: c#, ironpython

Say I have a python script 'calculator.py':

```
def Add(x,y) :
    return x + y;
```

I can instantiate a dynamic object from this like so:

```
var runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic calculator = runtime.UseFile("calculator.py");
int result = calculatore.Add(1, 2);
```

Is there a similarly easy way to instantiate the calculator from an in-memory string? What I would like to obtain is this:

```
var runtime = Python.CreateRuntime();
string script = GetPythonScript();
dynamic calculator = runtime.UseString(script); // this does not exist
int result = calculatore.Add(1, 2);
```

Where GetPythonScript() could be something like this:

```
string GetPythonScript() {
   return "def Add(x,y) : return x + y;"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic calculator = engine.CreateScope();
engine.Execute(GetPythonScript(), calculator);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
public string Evaluate( string scriptResultVariable, string scriptBlock )
{
    object result;

    try
    {
        ScriptSource source = 
            _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString( scriptBlock, SourceCodeKind.Statements );

        result = source.Execute( _scope );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        result = "Error executing code: " + ex;
    }

    return result == null ? "<null>" : result.ToString();
}
```